# How can i convert UTF-8 text to octal in Python 3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.7, octal

For example if i had to convert text to hex i can use

```
    import binascii
    x = input()
    print(str(binascii.b2a_hex(x.encode("utf-8")))[2:-2])
```

But I cant do that for octal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a great question, my mind went to something like this

```
x=[chr(x) for x in range(97,123)]
y=[oct(ord(i)) for i in x]
print(dict(zip(x,y)))
```

Comment: This worked 
`x = [chr(x) for x in range(32, 127)]

y = [oct(ord(i)) for i in x]

data = dict(zip(x, y))

z = 0

while z < len(x):

    print(data[x[z]][2:], end='')

    z += 1`